# What are the key challenges or limitations of Nicomachean Ethics when applied to the complexities and values of modern life?

Tags: aristotle, practical-ethics, virtue-ethics

Among the obvious ones I have come across are Aristotel's views on slavery and gender bias. I think Bernard Russel was unsatisfied with too much focus on rationality and overlooking emotions.

Comment: Nicomachean Ethics is my go to work on ethics. Personally the challenges for it is "is it still applicable now 2000 years in the future?" as far as I have found it is.